# JSF and HTML code returned as a String from Managed Bean possible?

Tags: html, jsf

In a previous web app I had made, I had used a String stored in my Managed bean to store a table in HTML, and returned it using a textOutput using JSF. I was wondering if this is possible with the HTML being returned containing JSF tags as well. For example:

My Managed Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "account")
@ViewScoped
public class Account{

String subForm = "";

/* getters and setters */

public String login()
{   
    boolean a = true;

    subForm = "<div id='userdivcor' class='form-inline has-success'>"
    + "<h:inputText id='corruser' type='text' value='#{account.username}'/>"
    + "</div>";

    return "loginError.xhtml";

}
```

My .xhtml file:

```
//some code leading to my form
<h:form id='form' method='post' onsubmit='return fullCheck()'>
    <h:outputText id="htmlStuffTwo" value="#{account.subForm}" escape="false"/> 
</h:form>
//remainder of code
```

Using h:outputText, could I render my returned String value without any errors? Currently, I am trying this on a larger scale, but when the text goes to render, my value is something crazy like:

```
 "hdOMomYGEH3QfwJfNhPPECOG2Pv3gt/2F1n7dFGGp6ItPlhzDREjEJTSax3NjvsVDdiBZQsB"
```

Just curious, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; JSF tags are interpreted on the server, but the content of a h:outputText is sent to the browser.

It is also worth noting that your current approach must disable HTML escaping to work, which is a security vulnerability if your table also contains user-supplied data.

The usual way is to have the tabular data in the backing bean, and use iterating jsf components such as a `h:datatable` (or its equivalent from whatever component library you are using), `ui:repeat`, or `c:foreach` to render the table.